# making certain links open in my Qt application

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a link let's say test://ABC.com/?a=123 and I want it to open in my Qt application when the URL is opened in a browser and then be able to process it and stuffs

Here's my issue. I don't know the search term for this feature so can't find docs nor blogs. If anyone knows what it is called please do tell me so I read some docs and get it working.

Comment: Have a look at here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24966317/1123146

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt - Getting source ( HTML code ) of a web page hosted on the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965972/qt-getting-source-html-code-of-a-web-page-hosted-on-the-internet)
Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica's answer

Comment: No, I'm looking for when the user clicks a link in firefox it opens in this application

Comment: You did not mention about browser in your question, please edit it!

Comment: What OS? Qt does not have means to do this. You'll have to use OS-dependent native code to register your application to handle URL scheme.

Comment: For Windows, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows and https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-Launching-applications-using-custom-browser-protocols

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm just getting into the topic and stumbled across this thread:

For Android it says "App Links"
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

and for iOS "Universal Links"
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing-apps-and-websites-to-link-to-your-content